# Virtual Environment creation failed in a shared directory in Ubuntu 18.04 in virtual box

Tags: python, virtualenv

I was trying to install flask in my Ubuntu 18.04 virtual machine in order to implement an API which send emails.
I following this tutorial:
`https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-flask-application`
when trying to set the virtual environment, I got this error with these two commands:

*- `python3 -m venv venv`

error :*

```
Error: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'lib' -> '/shared/BerryCert/Agent/Flask_Web/venv/lib64'
```

*- `Virtualenv venv`

error :*

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 365, in copytree
    raise Error(errors)
shutil.Error: [('/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6.so', '/shared/BerryCert/Agent/Flask_Web/venv/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6.so', "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1' -> '/shared/BerryCert/Agent/Flask_Web/venv/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6.so'"), ('/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so', '/shared/BerryCert/Agent/Flask_Web/venv/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so', "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1' -> '/shared/BerryCert/Agent/Flask_Web/venv/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so'")]
```

Could you please explain the issue to me?

Comment: it seems like a virtualbox issue  https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/209

Answer (score 1):

When creating the `virtualenv`, pass the `--always-copy` flag.

So something like: `virtualenv --always-copy [your-environment]`.

This should copy environment files - not symlink them.  There are sometimes issues with symlinks on virtualbox.  Hope this helps!

Comment: It helped a lot .... thank you very much ... but i didin't understood what was the problem exactly .... thank youuuu :) :) :)

Comment: So, VirtualBox creates folders with shared permissions (because they are accessible both from Ubuntu and whatever machine you are actually using).  This can create a problem with `virtualenv` as it cannot create the necessary symbolic links to aspects of the Python install you wish to use in your virtual environment.  Does that make sense?